# How do I using local bootstrap.min.css(version 4.0) work with nav nav-tabs class?

Tags: nav

The following code was normally show bootstrap nav & nav-tabs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!--script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script-->

<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active settingshead"><a href="#first" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
    <li class="settingshead"><a href="#second" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="first">
      <div class="namedesig">
        <h4>Dr. Jane Doe</h4>
        <p>PhD in Applied Physics</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="second">
    <div class="namedesig">
      <h4>Dr. Martin</h4>
      <p>PhD in Applied Chemistry</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I want to using Local css/bootstrap.min.css instead of https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The result is the nav & nav-tabs cannot show normally.

How can I using the local file of bootstrap.min.css and let the nav and nav-tabs normally display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrap cannot show with nav and nav-tabs, because I using local file Bootstrap 4.0  but I writing Bootstrap 3.0 Code.

The folloing code is Bootstrap 3.0 css, so why using online link was normally display.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Bootstrap 3.0 nav & nav-tabs Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active settingshead"><a href="#first" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
    <li class="settingshead"><a href="#second" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I just changed to Bootstrap 4.0 nav & nav-tabs code, everything was normally:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#first" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#second" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```